# R: Making subsetting of rows of a data.frame based on another data.frame independent

Tags: r, subset, rbind

I have an `input` data.frame with sample data

```
input <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Example2","Example7", "Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test6", "Test77"), class = "factor"), REFERENCE = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("EXAMPLE5", "REGION1", "REGION2", "REGION77"), class = "factor"), VALUE = structure(c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("120", "13", "14", "65", "89", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "REFERENCE", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
      NAME REFERENCE VALUE
1     Test   REGION1   120
2   Test77   REGION2    13
3    Test6  EXAMPLE5    14
4    Test2  EXAMPLE5    65
5 Example7  REGION77     B
6    Test3   REGION1    89
7 Example2  EXAMPLE5     C
```

And I have a second data.frame `filelist` in which data is ordered like this.

```
filelist <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("","Example2", "Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test6"), class = "factor"), REFERENCE = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("",  "EXAMPLE5", "REGION1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME","REFERENCE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
          NAME REFERENCE
    1     Test   REGION1
    2    Test3   REGION1
    3                   
    4    Test6  EXAMPLE5
    5    Test2  EXAMPLE5
    6 Example2  EXAMPLE5
```

`filelist` contains all the values that should be written out into separate data.frames grouped by the column `REFERENCE` (as in the code below).
Until now I did that by using the code below and subsetting the columns manually and then rbinding them together. Is there a way that this could be done independently?

```
# Manual selection REGION1
Test <- subset(input, NAME=="Test")
Test3 <- subset(input, NAME=="Test3")
# rbind them together
REGION1 <- rbind(Test, Test3)

# Manual selection EXAMPLE5
Test6 <- subset(input, NAME=="Test6")
Test2 <- subset(input, NAME=="Test2")
Example2 <- subset(input, NAME=="Example2")
# rbind them together
EXAMPLE5 <- rbind(Test6, Test2,Example2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful and what you are after. It seems that you want to merge input and filelist. Then, you want to create a data frame for each level of REFERENCE.

```
library(dplyr)

ana <- filelist %>%
            left_join(., input)

split(ana, f = ana$REFERENCE )

#[[1]]
#  NAME REFERENCE VALUE
#3                 <NA>

#$EXAMPLE5
#      NAME REFERENCE VALUE
#4    Test6  EXAMPLE5    14
#5    Test2  EXAMPLE5    65
#6 Example2  EXAMPLE5     C

#$REGION1
#   NAME REFERENCE VALUE
#1  Test   REGION1   120
#2 Test3   REGION1    89
```

**EDIT**

Big thanks to @Richard Scriven. Here is the final step the OP wanted.

```
list2env(split(ana, f = ana$REFERENCE )[-1], .GlobalEnv)

#> EXAMPLE5
#      NAME REFERENCE VALUE
#4    Test6  EXAMPLE5    14
#5    Test2  EXAMPLE5    65
#6 Example2  EXAMPLE5     C
```

Comment: great this is it! how could I convert this list into several data.frames?

Comment: @redshoe You can use `list2env(split(ana, f = ana$REFERENCE )[-1], .GlobalEnv)` then you have `EXAMPLE5` and `REGION1` as data frames in the global environment

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank you very much for this. I just spotted a post on google group now. Another great learning opportunity. Thank you.

Comment: @redshoe Glad this works for you. A part of credit goes to @Richard Scriven. I learned `list2env` from this.